# Why are small planar current loops of sufficiently small size interesting? (magnetic moments)

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment

In the book *Basic Laws of Electromagnetism* by Igor Irodov, He introduces force on a closed current-carrying loop as;

$$ F = \oint I \vec{dl} \times \vec{B}$$

And then he states the most interesting case of analysis is that of a small planar current loop of sufficiently small size and introduces a quantity $p_m$ to study this where $p_m$ is defined as:

$$ p_m = IS \vec{n}$$

Where $I$ is current, $S$ is the area bounded by the loop, and $ \vec{n}$ is normal to the loop and
supposedly  the force on it is given by:

$$ F= p_{in} \frac{ \partial B}{\partial n }$$

Where we are taking the directional derivative of $ \vec{B}$ in direction of the normal.

I have a few questions about this :

1. Why are small current loops interesting?
2. How did he go from the line integral into the other expression with force? (*)

---

*: **I couldn't find derivations of this formula but I tried to attempt a derivation on my own:**

I realized that stokes are not applicable here because the integral is a cross product instead of a dot. Hence, I thought of using what I learned in one form (??) and assumed a planar loop and field perpendicular to x-y plane.

$$ F  = I \oint B dx -B dy  $$

This looks like a flux one form but I'm not sure what to do after this.

---

??: I am not completely sure if the expressions I'm using are valid.

[The book can be found here](https://archive.org/details/IrodovBasicLawsOfElectromagnetism/page/n1/mode/2up), See page-158

Answer (score 0):

I think the author's main point is to introduce the concept of a magnetic moment (similar to a dipole moment) which can be thought of as a small current loop. The real magnetic moments (such as spin) are not really current loops... so it is just a pedagogical tool.

Regarding evaluating the moment - the integral here is a contour integral, so you have to choose a shape of your loop, parametrize it appropriately, and integrate along this contour. Square loop might be easier, while a circular loop might be a bit less artificial.

Comment: The way they've written it, it seems that  all loop shape should give same integral

Comment: Do you have experience with contour integrals? The notation may be misleading here.

Comment: I'm not sure of the precise definition but I think it means a line integral over a loop in this context. The confusion is due to the fact that contour integrals is usually used to describe integrals in the complex plane

Comment: Sorry, I might have used a wrong term: look up **line integrals** (contour integrals in the complex analysis are a particular case of those): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral

Comment: Anyhow, the idea is that you split the loop in small elements and add up their contributions.

Comment: Yeah, I do know what line integrals are but I can't seem to figure out how to integrate this one for a general field and general loop

Comment: Have you tried doing it for a square loop? For the general case: check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2654912/stokes-theorem-for-cross-product-with-line-element

Comment: after I use that theorem I get an integral with $ \nabla \cdot B$ .. can't figure out what to do with it

Comment: One of the Maxwell equations is $\nabla\cdot B = 0$.

Comment: I have assumed that it is normal and holds for non planar fields and have written a derivation, could you please check it?

Comment: "n^ is given by the right-hand-screw rule in relation to the sense of the line integral" is written in that post, any idea what it would mean?

Comment: Right-hand rule for the loops - how do you determine direction of the field generated by the current in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

The derivation of the formula:

$$ F = \oint I \vec{dl} \times \vec{B} =  - I \oint  \vec{B} \times \vec{dl}$$

Now using identity in this [MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2654912/stokes-theorem-for-cross-product-with-line-element)

$$ \oint \vec{B} \times \vec{dl} = \int_S (\nabla \cdot \vec{B}) \hat{n} - (\nabla B_i) n_i dS$$

The first term vanishes due to maxwell's identity that $ \nabla \cdot B=0$ and the second term is the directional derivative along the normal of the contour:

$$ \oint \vec{B} \times dl = -\int_S \frac{ \partial B}{\partial n} dS$$

Now for a 'small enough' loop, the above expression reduces to multiplying the rate of change of B along normal with the surface area. Plugging this back into our original expression:

$$ F = I \frac{ \partial B}{\partial n} dS$$

Which is the identity the book has written.

Comment: Ok, I am a bit puzzled how one would arrive at the direction since the left side is of scalars

Comment: The identity in question is a form of *Stokes' theorem* - it is a rather essential stuff in line integrals. The output is a vector, so Irodov takes some liberties in this case - he focuses on its magnitude.

Comment: So, 1. is my derivation correct, 2. how do I find direction now?

Comment: It is against the rules of Physics StackExchange to (ask to) correct/solve homework problems. It is okay to ask for help, if something blocks you - I think I gave you the key to the problem.

Comment: I do get your point, but I came to the realization that the quantity maybe more complex than what was thought initially. I made a post about it on MSE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3872314/what-does-it-mean-to-take-derivative-of-vector-in-a-direction)